using python to write a class for Car
I am trying to write a class for Car but I'm not getting the correct output. The brake data should subtract 5 from the speed data attribute each time it's called.
I tried the code below and the intended output for brake should be
brake 0: 20, brake1:15, brake2: 10, brake3:5 ,brake4:0
class Car:
    def __init__(self,__year_model, __make):
        self.__year_model = __year_model
        self.__make = __make
        self.__speed = 0


    def accelerate(self):
        self.__speed += 5


    def brake(self):
        self.__speed = -=5

    def get_speed(self):
        return self.__speed


from car import Car
my_car = Car("Corvette", 2022)

for a in range(0,5):
     b = my_car.accelerate()
     speed = my_car.get_speed()
     print(f"accelerate {a}: {speed}")


print()


for x in range(0,5):
    ac = my_car.brake()
    speed = my_car.get_speed()
    print(f"brake {x}: {speed}")

output:
accelerate 0: 5
accelerate 1: 10
accelerate 2: 15
accelerate 3: 20
accelerate 4: 25

brake 0: -5
brake 1: -5
brake 2: -5
brake 3: -5
brake 4: -5


self.__speed = -=5 This is a syntax error, because you have an extra = sign.  This can't be your real code.

I'm going to guess that your real code is self.__speed =- 5, which mistakenly uses  =- instead of -=.

Yes, I've corrected this part but I am still not receiving the intended ouput.

You say you corrected it, but the code in the question is still the same, so we have no idea what your actual code is now...

There was a typo in your code self.speed = -=5; I have modified that to self.speed += -5 (you could have also written that as self.speed -= 5).

Note: the same has been pointed out by @John-Gordon as well.

class Car:
    def __init__(self, year_model, make):
        self.year_model = year_model
        self.make = make
        self.speed = 0

    def accelerate(self):
        self.speed += 5

    def brake(self):
        self.speed += -5

    def get_speed(self):
        return self.speed

Accelerate
my_car = Car("Corvette", 2022)

for a in range(0,5):
     b = my_car.accelerate()
     speed = my_car.get_speed()
     print(f"accelerate {a}: {speed}")

## result
# accelerate 0: 5
# accelerate 1: 10
# accelerate 2: 15
# accelerate 3: 20
# accelerate 4: 25


Decelerate
for x in range(0,5):
    ac = my_car.brake()
    speed = my_car.get_speed()
    print(f"brake {x}: {speed}")

## result
# brake 0: 20
# brake 1: 15
# brake 2: 10
# brake 3: 5
# brake 4: 0

